# Incrementing i without for loop

Tags: python, selenium

I have this code:

```
for i in range(1, 7):

    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = "dtree0"]/div[' + str(i) +']/ a[2]').click()
```

I have some outer loop like this:

```py
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="dtree0"]/div/a')

names=[]

for elem in elements:

    names.append(elem.text)
    print(names)
#
# #     # click elements in the target level (names)
    for i in range(0, len(elements)):
        elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath ('//*[@id="dtree0"]/div/a')
        elem = elements[i]
#     #         # only click the elements in the names list (this level)
        if elem.text in names:
            names.remove(elem.text)
            try:
                elem.click()
            except WebDriverException:
                 pass  # ignore if elem is not clickable
        browser.find_elements_by_id("stree2").click()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a[1]/img').click ()

        browser.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/input').click()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/center/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[5]/a').click ()
        sleep (5)
```

I want to fit the upper code into the bottom code somewhere without the for loop. So the basic idea is to write the first loop without the for loop. The second block of code (outer loop) is just for context.

Comment: Why do you want to write the `for i in range(1, 7)` loop without using a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the logic why you are storing the names and then removing them from `names[]`. But, try the below which should answer your question.

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="dtree0"]/div/a')
names=[]
for elem in elements:
    names.append(elem.text)
    print(names)
# click elements in the target level (names)
for i in range(0, len(elements)):
    elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="dtree0"]/div/a')[i]
# only click the elements in the names list (this level)
    if elem.text in names:
        names.remove(elem.text)
        try:
            elem.click()
        except WebDriverException:
             pass  # ignore if elem is not clickable
    browser.find_element_by_id("stree2").click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a[1]/img').click ()

    browser.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/input').click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/center/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[5]/a').click ()
    sleep (5)
```

Comment: No, I want the increment for this line: browser.find_element_by_id("stree2").click() where after stree it changes from 2....100